# thickbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, thickbox

I am using thickbox in asp.net and everything works fine. I load it, have textboxes and dropdowns in it. I also made modal=true, so it only closes when I click the "Thank you" button.

The problem is that behind in the aspx.vb file, I need the data from the thick box, so I can insert and update my database. How can i do that?

Right now all that is happening is that onclicking the button the thickbox closes, but how do I send data to .vb file in backend?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your 'thank you' button calls a plugin function like $.thickbox.close();
have you try to add your server controls like  in your thickbox div? try to add it inside the thickbox div and trigget its click event.